# Use Storext (or just Virtus) with nested array or hash objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hstore, jsonb, virtus

I have a postgres DB backing my Rails app with a class with a jsonb column

```
class Product < AR::B
  include Storext.model(data: {})

  store_attributes :data do
    thing_one String
    thing_two Boolean # Not actually showing up in the `data` hash
    foos      FooCollection[Foo]
  end
end

class FooCollection < Array
  def <<(obj)
    if Hash
      super(Coupon.new(obj)
    else
      # Other coersions
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Storext.model

  attribute :id,                Integer
  attribute :price,             Float
  attribute :regular_price,     Float
end
```

But Foo in the terminal is returning `undefined method after_initialize for Foo:Class`

Is there a way to nest `Storext` models the same way it is with `Virtus`? And if so is there an idiomatic way to add validations on the nested classes? (Abandoning Storext, and a pure Virtus solution would also answer the question)

Maybe this is an A/B problem because I just included Virtus in FooCollection and it also disappeared from the `data` hash (which I consider weird since `Storext` is based on `Virtus` and can accept `Virtus` methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storext was created to type-cast simple values only. I haven't played around storing complex objects in Virtus myself, and I'm still undecided whether or not that should be part of Storext. While it uses Virtus in the background, I don't think it should implement everything Virtus can do.

A little late to the party, but I hope this helps.

Comment: For what it's worth Virtus was also too rigid (or possibly I didn't know how to use Virtus well enough) for what I was trying to do. So, I ended up just writing something custom. It's good to see that this isn't how it's supposed to work, because that is always the fear, do I not understand X or does X just not do this thing?

Comment: Yes, also, it complicates the code :) Cool glad to hear you found a solution.